# msbuild aspnet mvc framework missing project reference

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have an asp.net mvc framework 4.5.2 project (Project A) which references another project (Project B) built with the same framework. Project A also references a bunch of other projects that also reference Project B. The solution was created in VS2017 and everything builds and publishes in VS2017 without any problems.

However, when I try to use msbuild (from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin) on Project A, I get a build error saying it cannot locate the project info for Project B. The error message is 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Cannot find project info for [Project B]'

I've tried setting the msbuild parameter /p:ReferencePath to the path of Project B csproj but I still get the same error. From googling there were some suggestions about changing the framework to 4.6.1 or 4.6.2. That doesn't fix the issue either.

How is the build process different between msbuild command line and VS2017? Have I missed anything obvious? Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce. It works fine on my side with latest Visual Studio 15.3. What is the project type of Project B and the version of your Visual Studio? Could you please share us some more detail steps so that we can reproduce this issue or you can create a new sample to reproduce this issue then share it to us.

Comment: Project B is a class library built with Framework 4.5.2. I forgot to mention that i'm trying to use msbuild to build and publish. The parameters I'm using are: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="[name of publish file]" /p:Configuration=Release

Comment: I have also published it but not reproduce it. According to the question, all project are .net framework not .net core, but the error was "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets", which is related to .net core. So you should make sure if there is any .net core project in your solution or could reproduce this issue by new .net framework project?

Comment: There are definitely no .net core projects but some of the nuget packages are .net core compatible. I've tried and failed to reproduce this problem with another solution. I'm going to have to explore other options. Thanks for all your effort in trying to help.

Comment: that`s ok. please let us to know you can reproduce this issue.